# How to get the current activity after activity has been changed

Tags: android, android-activity, callback, android-dialog

I'm using nearby connections to create a connection between devices. When a connection has been established, the activity is changed. Now if a device disconnects then a callback is called, but its received in the old activity. Now I want to show an AlertDialog, but the dialog is never shown because it shows on the old activity. How can show the dialog on the new activity?

I'm using nearby connections like this: [URL](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/manage-connections)

```
private Activity mActivity;

public RemoteConnection(Activity activity){
    mActivity = activity;
} 

  // For simplicity I did only include this method
  @Override
  public void onDisconnected(String endpointId) {
    // We've been disconnected from this endpoint. No more data can be
    // sent or received.
    new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
      .setTitle("Disconnection")
      .setMessage("Other device is disconnected")
      .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
      .show();
  }
```

The dialog should be shown on the current activity

Comment: you can use the broadcast receiver for this purpose.

Comment: keeping Activity references in fields is a great way to create memory leaks. Don't do it

Comment: @TimCastelijns Was thinking that was a bad idea. But have to use it so many times during in the nearby connections. But I guess I should pass it, in all methods instead?

Answer (score 0):

Write a method in your activities as:

```
public void showAlert(activity)
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
  .setTitle("Disconnection")
  .setMessage("Other device is disconnected")
  .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
  .show();
}
```

and change following code :

```
@Override
 public void onDisconnected(String endpointId) {
// We've been disconnected from this endpoint. No more data can be
// sent or received.
new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
  .setTitle("Disconnection")
  .setMessage("Other device is disconnected")
  .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
  .show();
```

}

To:

```
@Override
 public void onDisconnected(String endpointId) {
// We've been disconnected from this endpoint. No more data can be
// sent or received.
if(((YourActivityA)activity) != null)
{
    ((YourActivityA)activity).showAlert(activity);
}
else if(((YourActivityB)activity) != null)
{
    ((YourActivityB)activity).showAlert(activity);
}
}
```

Comment: This will throw a `ClassCastException` if `activity` is of type `YourActivityB`. This is a brute force approach and not recommended. Imagine if you had 20 or 100 activities.

Answer (score 0):

Use an event bus implementation or send the callback using `sendBroadcast()` and have each `Activity` register a `BroadcastReceiver` in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`.